# Multiple undeclared identifier error compiling simple Modelica code with OpenModelica v1.14.1 (64-bit)

Tags: compiler-errors, modelica, openmodelica

the C source code of the following simple Modelica model generated by OpenModelica fails to compile. This is awkward because the C compiler complains about missing symbols which should be generated automatically by the tool. I can add, however, that the model does not check with Dymola. Several errors are reported, the first one being `The operand in edge(particles[bIdx].alive) must be a variable.`, which, as far as I understood the language, is not the case.

I hope that with the source code below someone can shed a bit of light about this situation and can establish if I did something wrong (the model should not check out well) or I found a bug in the C source generator (and Dymola translator).

Cheers!

```
model TestAlgorithm

  import SI = Modelica.SIunits;

  model Particle

    import SI = Modelica.SIunits;

    SI.Length s "Position of the particle";   
    SI.Velocity v "Velocity of the particle";   
    Real theta "Quantity transported by the particle";   
    Real alpha(min = 0, max = 1);   
    Boolean alive;
//    Integer alive; // This doen't help
//    Real alive; // This don't even translate

  equation

    der(s) = v;
    der(theta) = 0;

  end Particle;


  parameter SI.Length L = 10 "Length of the box";
  parameter Integer nParticles = 4 "Number of particles";
  parameter SI.Velocity v = 1.5; 
  parameter SI.Length Ds = L/nParticles;

  Particle particles[nParticles+1];

protected

  Integer aIdx;
  Integer bIdx;

initial algorithm

  aIdx := 1;
  bIdx := nParticles + 1;

initial equation

  for i in 1:(nParticles + 1) loop

    particles[i].s = (i - 1)*Ds; // Initial position of the particles
    particles[i].alive = true;
//    particles[i].alive = 1; // To be used with Integer and Real
    particles[i].v = v; // Initial velocity of the paraticles 
  end for;


  for i in 1:integer(nParticles/4) loop

    particles[i].theta = 2;   
  end for;

  for i in (integer(nParticles/4)+1):(nParticles + 1) loop

    particles[i].theta = 1;   
  end for;

  // Note! Moving alpha initialization from initial algorithm to initial equation made the model translable to C (still not compiling)
  particles[1].alpha = 0.5;

  for i in 2:nParticles loop
    particles[i].alpha = 1.0;
  end for;

  particles[nParticles+1].alpha = 0.5;

algorithm

  when 
   (edge(particles[bIdx].alive) and pre(particles[bIdx].alive)) or 
   (edge(particles[aIdx].alive) and pre(particles[aIdx].alive)) then
//   (change(particles[bIdx].alive) and pre(particles[bIdx].alive)==1) or // To be used with Integer and Real
//   (change(particles[aIdx].alive) and pre(particles[aIdx].alive)==1) then // To be used with Integer and Real

    if v >= 0 then

      aIdx := bIdx;
      bIdx := mod(bIdx - 1 - 1, nParticles + 1) + 1;
    else

      bIdx := aIdx;
      aIdx := mod(aIdx + 1 - 1, nParticles + 1) + 1;
    end if;
  end when;

  //(nParticles + 1)*3 equations
  for i in 1:nParticles + 1 loop

    particles[i].alive := (particles[i].s + Ds/2 > 0) and (particles[i].s - Ds/2 < L);
//    particles[i].alive := if (particles[i].s + Ds/2 > 0) and (particles[i].s - Ds/2 < L) then 1 else 0; // To be used with Integer and Real
    particles[i].alpha := if (particles[i].s  - Ds/2) < 0 then particles[i].s/Ds + 1/2 else if (particles[i].s + Ds/2) > L then (particles[i].s - L)/Ds + 1/2 else 1;
  end for;

equation

  when 
   (edge(particles[bIdx].alive) and pre(particles[bIdx].alive)) or 
   (edge(particles[aIdx].alive) and pre(particles[aIdx].alive)) then
//   (change(particles[bIdx].alive) and pre(particles[bIdx].alive)==1) or // To be used with Integer and Real
//   (change(particles[aIdx].alive) and pre(particles[aIdx].alive)==1) then // To be used with Integer and Real

    if v >= 0 then

      reinit(particles[aIdx].s, particles[mod(aIdx + 1 - 1, nParticles+1) + 1].s - Ds);
      reinit(particles[aIdx].theta, particles[aIdx].theta); // Loop condition for debug purposes
    else

      reinit(particles[bIdx].s, particles[mod(bIdx - 1 - 1, nParticles+1) + 1].s + Ds);
      reinit(particles[bIdx].theta, particles[bIdx].theta); // Loop condition for debug purposes
    end if;
  end when;

  for i in 1:nParticles + 1 loop
    particles[i].v = v;
  end for;

  annotation ();
end TestAlgorithm;
```

The error message is

```
C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.14.1-64bit//share/omc/scripts/Compile.bat TestAlgorithm gcc mingw64 parallel 8 0
PATH = "C:\PROGRA~1\OPENMO~1.1-6\tools\msys\mingw64\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\OPENMO~1.1-6\tools\msys\mingw64\bin\..\..\usr\bin;"
mingw32-make: Entering directory 'C:/Users/ASOPPE~1/AppData/Local/Temp/OPENMO~1/OMEdit/TESTAL~1'
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.14.1-64bit//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=TestAlgorithm -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=1 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o TestAlgorithm.o TestAlgorithm.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.14.1-64bit//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=TestAlgorithm -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=1 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o TestAlgorithm_functions.o TestAlgorithm_functions.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.14.1-64bit//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=TestAlgorithm -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=1 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o TestAlgorithm_records.o TestAlgorithm_records.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.14.1-64bit//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=TestAlgorithm -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=1 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o TestAlgorithm_01exo.o TestAlgorithm_01exo.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.14.1-64bit//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=TestAlgorithm -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=1 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o TestAlgorithm_02nls.o TestAlgorithm_02nls.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.14.1-64bit//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=TestAlgorithm -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=1 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o TestAlgorithm_03lsy.o TestAlgorithm_03lsy.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.14.1-64bit//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=TestAlgorithm -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=1 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o TestAlgorithm_04set.o TestAlgorithm_04set.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.14.1-64bit//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=TestAlgorithm -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=1 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o TestAlgorithm_05evt.o TestAlgorithm_05evt.c
TestAlgorithm.c: In function 'TestAlgorithm_eqFunction_60':
TestAlgorithm.c:339:5: error: 'particles' undeclared (first use in this function)
     particles[aIdx].s = (&data->localData[0]->realVars[0] /* particles[1].s STATE(1,particles[1].v) */)[calc_base_index_dims_subs(1, 5, modelica_integer_mod(data->localData[0]->integerVars[0] /* aIdx DISCRETE */ + ((modelica_integer) 1) - ((modelica_integer) 1), tmp10) + ((modelica_integer) 1))] - data->simulationInfo->realParameter[0] /* Ds PARAM */;
     ^
TestAlgorithm.c:339:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
TestAlgorithm.c:339:15: error: 'aIdx' undeclared (first use in this function)
     particles[aIdx].s = (&data->localData[0]->realVars[0] /* particles[1].s STATE(1,particles[1].v) */)[calc_base_index_dims_subs(1, 5, modelica_integer_mod(data->localData[0]->integerVars[0] /* aIdx DISCRETE */ + ((modelica_integer) 1) - ((modelica_integer) 1), tmp10) + ((modelica_integer) 1))] - data->simulationInfo->realParameter[0] /* Ds PARAM */;
               ^
TestAlgorithm.c: In function 'TestAlgorithm_eqFunction_59':
TestAlgorithm.c:359:5: error: 'particles' undeclared (first use in this function)
     particles[aIdx].theta = (&data->localData[0]->realVars[5] /* particles[1].theta STATE(1) */)[calc_base_index_dims_subs(1, 5, data->localData[0]->integerVars[0] /* aIdx DISCRETE */)];
     ^
TestAlgorithm.c:359:15: error: 'aIdx' undeclared (first use in this function)
     particles[aIdx].theta = (&data->localData[0]->realVars[5] /* particles[1].theta STATE(1) */)[calc_base_index_dims_subs(1, 5, data->localData[0]->integerVars[0] /* aIdx DISCRETE */)];
               ^
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.14.1-64bit//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=TestAlgorithm -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=1 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o TestAlgorithm_06inz.o TestAlgorithm_06inz.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.14.1-64bit//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=TestAlgorithm -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=1 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o TestAlgorithm_07dly.o TestAlgorithm_07dly.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.14.1-64bit//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=TestAlgorithm -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=1 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o TestAlgorithm_08bnd.o TestAlgorithm_08bnd.c
<builtin>: recipe for target 'TestAlgorithm.o' failed
```

Comment: Sorry, I see that OM is using gcc. VS2017 is used by Dymola.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify:

1. The argument to edge must indeed be a variable, Modelica 3.4 states:

edge: Is expanded into "(b and not pre(b))" for Boolean variable b. The same restrictions as for the pre() operator apply (e.g. not to be used in function classes).

pre: Returns the "left limit" y(tpre) of variable y(t) at a time instant t. (And other text clarifying that it is indeed a variable.)

2. Ignoring (1) the when-statement cannot trigger, since 
   `edge(particles[bIdx].alive) and pre(particles[bIdx].alive` is according to the definition above the same as
   `particles[bIdx].alive and not pre(particles[bIdx].alive) and pre(particles[bIdx].alive)`; which can be simplified to false.

The problem with allowing `pre(v[bIdx])` is that it is not clear if it is intended to be `pre(v)[bIdx]` - or `pre(v)[pre(bIdx)]`; the latter would work similarly as `pre(b)` for `Boolean b=v[bIdx];`. (Note: Indexing of pre(...) isn't legal Modelica; I'm just using it informally.)

Comment: Well, there is something I am missing. Why `particles[bIdx].alive` is not a variable?

Comment: I try to answer my comment myself, but I just started studing the language so it could be wrong. 'particles[bIdx].alive' is an expression evaluating to a type `Boolean`. However, the expression contains a symbol which is another variable `bIdx`, so, although the expression identifies a single scalar variable, another variables is required for its resolution, which makes it more like a call to a function with state than a reference to a determined memory location. Btw, thank you for the two insights i think I can now come up with a solution.